# How to invoke CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW method in C++ Windows Desktop Application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to create a desktop application in windows by c++.

In this application I would like to invoke Windows Security dialog as Chrome whenever we want to show the password.

When I add the code below to my project and build then an error occurred:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol **imp__CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW@36 referenced in function "int **stdcall ShowWindowsSecurityDialog(struct HWND** *)" (?ShowWindowsSecurityDialog@@YGHPAUHWND**@@@Z)    TestPromptWindowsSecurity   D:\Works\Learn\WindowsApp\TestPromptWindowsSecurity\TestPromptWindowsSecurity\TestPromptWindowsSecurity.obj 1

Here is my code. I put it in ShowWindowsSecurityDialog method and call it after click button.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK ShowWindowsSecurityDialog(HWND hDlg)
{
    DWORD dwResult;
    PVOID pvInAuthBlob = NULL;
    ULONG cbInAuthBlob = 0;
    PVOID pvAuthBlob = NULL;
    ULONG cbAuthBlob = 0;
    CREDUI_INFOW ui;
    ULONG ulAuthPackage = 0;
    BOOL fSave = FALSE;
    ui.cbSize = sizeof(ui);
    ui.hwndParent = hDlg;
    ui.pszMessageText = L"The Proxy Server requires user name and password";
    ui.pszCaptionText = L"Proxy Authentication";
    ui.hbmBanner = NULL;

    dwResult = CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentialsW(
        &ui,            // Customizing information
        0,              // Error code to display
        &ulAuthPackage, // Authorization package
        pvInAuthBlob,   // Credential byte array
        cbInAuthBlob,   // Size of credential input buffer
        &pvAuthBlob,    // Output credential byte array
        &cbAuthBlob,    // Size of credential byte array
        &fSave,         // Select the save check box.
        CREDUIWIN_GENERIC);
    if (dwResult == NO_ERROR)
    {
    }
    else
    {
   
    }

    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

What is wrong here ? How can I make this function ?

Comment: Did you add the `Credui.lib` library to your build?

Comment: Those MSDN doc pages tell you which library to link to at the bottom.